# Android Studios / IntelliJ equivalent of "Add package folders to sources" feature in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, intellij-idea, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In Netbeans, whenever I want to add an external folder (outside of the project directory) to my list of sources, I do something like this:

*** Project Properties >> Sources >> Add Folder ***

[image: Project Properties >> Sources >> Add Folder]

I just click the folder where all my .java files are and I never have to mess around with any scripts by hand, the file directory navigator handles it for me. Is there an equivalent to this in Android Studios (the newer IntelliJ based version), or do I have to mess around with the "build.gradle" file?

How do I get my .java files from my Dropbox folder into my project?

[image: Android Studios]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

Go to File | Project Structure

Then within that dialog, go to Modules, then click the green "+" button, then follow the instructions to add your files.

(I'm on IntelliJ, but most of it is the same)

Comment: "File > Project Structure" gives me tabs for "SDK Location", "Project", and "Modules: app" on the far left. On the top I have tabs for "Properties", "Signing", "Flavors", "Build Types" and "Dependencies". Under "Dependencies", there's an option for "add file dependency", but it won't let me add any .java files that are in my Dropbox folder, only files within the Android Studios project.